# Wait for element to be defined in Angular2

Tags: angularjs, dom, angular, google-visualization, primeng

I'm trying to embed a Google Chart in a [PrimeNG tab](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tabview). I'm using a fork of the [Angular 2 Google Chart package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-google-chart). The first time I route to the page with the chart, everything works as expected. However, when I navigate away, and return I get the following error:

> Error in ./MyChartComponent class MyChartComponent - inline
>   template:1:5 caused by: The container #my_chart is not defined.

This is the same error one would get if they were trying to draw a chart into a div that didn't exist. As far as I can tell,

1) it works the first time because there is a delay while the charts library is retrieved, allowing for the `<div id="my_chart"...>` element to be rendered.
2) when the route is reopened, a sequence of events fires that results in the charting library to try and set the content of of the div before the div has been included in the DOM.

The charting components work fine when they are not embeded in the PrimeNG tabs. I suspect the order in which events occurs has been broken by this. I found a reference that said PrimeNG tabs put content into `<ng-content>`. If this breaks some sort of Parent/Child relationship in the components lifecycle, then I further suppose that I need some way to wait on setting the `@Input` to the chart component until after the "my_chart" div exists.

I've dug through the documentation for the various Angular life cycle hooks, but haven't been able to solve this issue. Any adivice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the resolve attribute in setting up your route:

```
{
    path: '',
    resolve: { chartData: ChartResolver },
    component: MyChartComponent 
}
```

Then in your component pull that data in:

```
ngOnInit() {
    //The 'data' gets loaded into the snapshot by the route resolver 
    this.chartData = this.route.snapshot.data['chartData'];
  }
```

Then you have to create the Resolver class:

```
@Injectable()
export class ChartResolver implements Resolve<ChartData> {

  constructor(private http:Http) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<ChartData> {

    //Doesn't have to be a server call, as long as it returns the data
    return this.http.get("/url-to-chart-info)
      .map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

You'll have to import everything correctly and I don't know if you have a Typescript class for the data, but something in this direction should work. This should make the data or whatever else you need to have ready available before the template is rendered.

Hopefully that helps, it doesn't fully address your question, more part 2, but the resolver is the best way to get everything ready before you need to render.